# Gif aparecer por cima da page

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu tenho esta `img` que aparece um `gif` com efeito de `load`:

```
<img id="loading" src="~/images/loading.gif" alt="Updating ..." style="display: none;" />

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#loading').hide();
$('#btn-substituir').click(
    function () {
        $('#loading').show();
    }
);
});
```

E esta função para aparecer, porém eu gostaria que aparacesse por cima da página, e no meio. Da forma que está, ele desce os dados, e aparece a imagem carregando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode incluir algumas propriedades CSS ao elemento no próprio código:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#loading').hide();
   $('#btn-substituir').click(
    function () {
        $('#loading')
        .css({
           position: "fixed", // fixa o elemento
           zIndex: "9", // coloca o elemento por cima dos outros
           top: "50%", // move 50% do topo
           left: "50%", // move 50% da esquerda
           transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)" // centraliza
        })
        .show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="loading" src="https://media1.tenor.com/images/928ee5be0dfe90bfd21f5b3f9f660a51/tenor.gif?itemid=13055476" alt="Updating ..." style="display: none;" />
<button id="btn-substituir">Clique</button>
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho, como posso escurecer a tela de baixo, e deixar o `img` por cima??

Comment: Aí vc teria que colocar a imagem dentro de uma div.

Comment: Terá que colocar o id e o style="display: none;" na div. Veja um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/v3qek0r6/

Comment: Certinho, obrigado.

Comment: Vc controla a transparência no valor `.5` do rgba, que vai de 0 a 1. O `.5` é a metade.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer essa alteração usando CSS da seguinte maneira:

```
.loading-div {
//Deixará sua div posicionada no topo esquerdo da tela com tamanho de 100%
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#loading-img {
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}
```

Coloque seu loading dentro de uma div e use o .show nesta div:

```
<div class="loading-div">
<img id="loading-img" src="~/images/loading.gif" alt="Updating ..." style="display: none;" />
</div>
```